# Send pictures to a new window

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make a slideshow of pictures and send them to an another window. But after selecting images and pressing the button for showing slideshows, nothing happens. I'm using firebug to detect bugs and when I'm going wrong. But I'm not getting any error from firebug so I gotta ask you guys. This is my code.
        var infoBox;
        var formTag;
        var imgUrlList;
        var imgTextList;
        var windVar;
        var urlList;
        var textList;

```
    function init() {
        var i;
        infoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("outerBox");
        for (i=0; i<infoBox.length; i++) {
            infoBox[i].onmouseover = showInfoBox;
            infoBox[i].onmouseout = hideInfoBox;
        }
        formTag = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i=0; i<formTag.length; i++) {
            formTag[i].onclick = checkedBox;
        }

        windVar = null;
        imgTextList = [];
        imgUrlList = [];
    }
    window.onload = init;

    function showInfoBox() {
        var showInfo;
        showInfo = this.getElementsByClassName("innerBox")[0];
        showInfo.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function hideInfoBox() {
        var hideInfo;
        hideInfo = this.getElementsByClassName("innerBox")[0];
        hideInfo.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    function checkedBox() {
        var ImgNode, ImgTag;
        for (i=0; i<formTag.length; i++) {
            imgNode = this.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild;
            imgTag = imgNode.nextSibling
            if (this.checked) {
                imgTag.className = "markedImg";
            }
            else { 
                imgTag.className = "unmarkedImg";
            }
        }
    }
    function slideShowBtn() {
        var url, i, filename;
        imgUrlList.length = 0;
        imgTextList.length = 0;
        for (i=0; i<formTag.length; i++) {
            if (formTag.checked) {
                url = infoBox.firstChild.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].src;
                filename = infoBox.firstChild.getElementsByTagName("span")[i].src;
                    imgUrlList.push(url);
                    imgTextList.push(filename);
            }
            else break;
        }
        newWindow(700,600,"slideshow.htm");
    }

    function newWindow(width,height,fileName) {
        var windProporties;
        windProporties = "top=100, left=100,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=" + width + ",height=" + height;
        if (windVar != null) if (windVar.closed == false) windVar.close();
        windVar = window.open(fileName,"bildspel",windProporties);
    }
```

The formTag variabel is from a checkbox-input-tag. And it's from that I decide which pictures are selected and will be moved to the new page. ImgTextList and imgUrlList are global variables that'll also be in the next window. infoBox is a reference to a div class which is called OuterBox and inside it is an another div-class named innerBox, it's in the innerBox classdiv which the img and span-tags are. The code for the slideshow is already written and I'm just writing code for sending the variables to it.

**Edit:** I should have been a little more informative. But here's the code for the slideshow part where window.opener is present. And I've added all the remaining code that's above. How do you embed files?

```
   // JavaScript for the slideshow page

    // ----- Global variables -----
    var imgUrlList = window.opener.imgUrlList; // Array with filenames of selected images. Initialized to an empty array.
    var imgTextList = window.opener.imgTextList; // Array with image texts of selected images. Initialized to an empty array.
    var slideshowMenu = null; // Reference to the image menu.
    var slideshowImg = null; // Reference to the slideshow img tag.
    var slideshowText = null; // Reference to the tag for the image text.

    // ---- Create the image menu and show the first image. Also attach event handlers. ----
    function initSlideshow() {
// Create a image list from the content of the variable imgUrlList
        var HTMLcode = "<select id='imgMenu'>";
        for (var i=0; i<imgTextList.length; i++) {
            HTMLcode += "<option>" + imgTextList[i] + "</option>";
        } // End for
        HTMLcode += "</select>";
        document.getElementById("iMenu").innerHTML = HTMLcode; // Add the select and option tags to the HTML code
        slideshowMenu = document.getElementById("imgMenu"); // Save a reference to the menu's select tag
        slideshowMenu.selectedIndex = 0; // Select the first option in the menu
        slideshowImg = document.getElementById("slideshowBox").getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
        slideshowText = document.getElementById("slideshowBox").getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        // Show the first image
        slideshowImg.src = imgUrlList[0];
        slideshowText.innerHTML = imgTextList[0];
        // Attach event handlers
        var slideshowButtons = document.getElementById("slideshowForm").getElementsByTagName("input");
        slideshowButtons[0].onclick = showPrevImage;
        slideshowButtons[1].onclick = showNextImage;
        slideshowMenu.onchange = showSelectedImage;
    } // End initSlideshow
    window.onload = initSlideshow;

    // ---- Show previous image in the list (menu) ----
    function showPrevImage() {
        var ix = slideshowMenu.selectedIndex; // Index for the current image
        if (ix > 0) { // If it's not already the first image
            slideshowMenu.selectedIndex = ix-1;
            slideshowImg.src = imgUrlList[ix-1];
            slideshowText.innerHTML = imgTextList[ix-1];
        }
    } // End showPrevImage

    // ---- Show next image in the list (menu) ----
    function showNextImage() {
        var ix = slideshowMenu.selectedIndex; // Index for the current image
        if (ix < slideshowMenu.length-1) { // If it's not already the last image
            slideshowMenu.selectedIndex = ix+1;
            slideshowImg.src = imgUrlList[ix+1];
            slideshowText.innerHTML = imgTextList[ix+1];
        }
    } // End showNextImage

    // ---- Show selected image in the list (menu) ----
    function showSelectedImage() {
        var ix = slideshowMenu.selectedIndex; // Index for the selected image
        slideshowImg.src = imgUrlList[ix];
        slideshowText.innerHTML = imgTextList[ix];
    } // End showSelectedImage
```

Comment: Narrow it down. What's the simplest version of this that still works?

Comment: You need to get closer to the bug. Also, this is just a part of all code, it's hard to find something wrong like this...

Answer (score 0):

Um, you never do anything to send it. Either pass it as a querystring parameter or have the child reference a global variable in the opener.

```
var foo = window.opener.imgUrlList;
```